# Prove an eigenvector for two matrices is also the eigenvector for the product of those matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

So let's assume that A and B are both nxn matrices, and that u is an eigenvector for both A corresponding to lambda one and B corresponding to lambda 2. I need to prove that u is also the eigenvector for the product AB.

Initial Thoughts:
A*u=x'=B*u
A*u=B*u

I'm really not quite sure about where to go with this one, unfortunately for me my teacher has an affinity for proofs.

Comment: $(B\textbf{u})=\lambda_2\textbf{u}$ Hence $A(B\textbf{u})=\lambda_1\lambda_2\textbf{u}$

Comment: Just a comment: the teacher has an affinity for proofs because that's what mathematics is all about. Mathematics teachers have an affinity for proofs like athletics coaches have an affinity for running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$Au=\lambda_1 u$ and $Bu=\lambda_2 u$. Then $ABu=A(\lambda_2 u)=\lambda_2Au=\lambda_2 \lambda_1 u$

We are done

Answer (score 1):

Proofs are all about what fact follows from what other fact. A correct proof starts with a known fact and finishes with the fact you want to show.

In your case, the known fact is: $u$ is an eigenvector for $A$ and $B$.

The fact you want to show is: $u$ is an eigenvector for $AB$.

The first thing you should do is to write defined properties (in your case "$u$ is an eigenvector for $A$" as what they are defined as (in your case "There exists such a $\lambda$ that $Au = \lambda u$").

Rewriting all your statements leaves you with:

- You know that there exist such $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ that $Au=\lambda_1 u$ and $Bu = \lambda_2 u$.
- You need to show there exists such $\lambda_3$ that $(AB)u = \lambda_3 u$.

Now comes the part where you need some experience to make the correct step. In general, you can either start with the statement you know and try to derive the statement you need, or you can dig deeper into the statement you need to prove. In this case, the latter is what you need to do, i.e. you need to say to yourself "well, I need to show that $(AB)u = \lambda_3u$, but wait, I first need to find out what $(AB)u$ **is**!".

So, you take a look at $(AB)u$ and notice that, by definition:

$$(AB)u = A(Bu)$$

But, now you can see that you already know that $Bu = \lambda_2 u$, so you write

$$(AB)u = A(\lambda_2 u) = \lambda_2 Au$$

And now you remember that $Au=\lambda_1 u$ and you can write

$$(AB)u = \lambda_2(Au) = \lambda_2(\lambda_1 u)$$

Noticing that that's exactly what you need to prove, if you set $\lambda_3=\lambda_1\cdot \lambda_2$, you are done.